# Jmeter thread creation in the middle

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter for performance testing. Mine is not a typical web application. Let me explain from the UI point of view. The UI when it receives push notifications from the server has to spawn new activities based on the notification. How do I simuate this using JMeter? Jmeter will be in place of UI and it will place the requests to the server. JMeter will receive notifications from the server. Based on the notification, JMeter has to create new activities (or new requests). Basically, Jmeter is used for request-response in linear format. Can I suddenly spawn threads in the middle of a linear flow? Is there any plugin available for this?

Comment: Depends on what mechanism your UI is notified to create new activities. If it is using web sockets, then there is hope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557531/stress-testing-websockets-in-jmeter - but it seems like this JMeter plugin is pooly documented.

Answer (score 0):

you can pause a thread (putting it in an infinite loop + sleep) waiting for some property to change. Use JMeter-Plugins inter-thread communication to wake these threads up.