# Is it possible to run JMeter samplers concurrently?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, jmeter

So to explain my situation:

I have a JMeter test plan that runs some test groups constantly in a loop. In addition to this I need to have multiple sampler requests go through together each minute (to simulate spiked usages). I can't set a constant timer to delay each of these because some may finish up quicker than others and they won't be in sync.

Is there a way to make multiple test groups send a request every minute the test is running?

OR

Is there a way to put all these samplers in 1 thread group and make them all run concurrently?

Comment: Here is yet another approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401079/jmeter-thread-creation-in-the-middle/19403557#19403557

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm able to understand your use case, you need 2 Thread Groups.

1. First Thread Group which is SOAP Sampler A
2. Second Thread Group which is SOAP Sampler B

Then you need to set [different variables for both thread groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) to make them behave according to your use case and implement spikes you need.

Important: make sure that "Run Thread Groups consecutively" under your test plan is **UNCHECKED** elsewise you'll be having SOAP Sampler B running **after** SOAP Sampler A, not in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider your scenario is,

```
5 Users hitting 5 URLs(samplers) simultaneously.
```

So what you need to do is, in your **Test Plan**, add **5 Thread Groups**. In each Thread Group configure the number of **Threads to 5** and **Ramp Up to 0**.

Now, add **one HTTP Request sampler** in each **Thread Group**. Configure each sampler according to the URL you want to test.

Add **Listener(s)** to your **Test Plan**. Save the Test Plan and Run your test.

**Make sure you haven't selected the "Run Thread Groups consecutively" in the Test Plan.**

Comment: How is . possible to achieve this without create multiple thread groups, because in my case I have more users (1000's)

Comment: Even if you have a 1000 users, your HTTP Requests would be same, isn't it? So for each Thread Group for the respective HTTP Request you can assign 1000 users (Threads).