# How to configure csv data set in websocket sampler using jmeter?

Tags: testing, websocket, jmeter, performance-testing

I am using jmeter tool for websocket testing. I need to create multiple orders with multiple users and for that i need to set up csv data set. How can i use it in websocket sampler? As i can see that the request is sent in "Request Data" section but how should i give the variable names there and how would it read through csv?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Websocket plugin you're using, but see this for best solution:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110121/460802

If you follow the one we advise , then just add a [CSV Data Set config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your plan filling required fields:

[image]

Pay attention to Variable Names (example here myData1).

You can then use it through:

> ${myData1}

Comment: I have added it through websocket sampler but its not picking up the data from csv.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a bug in the "websocket sampler" plugin you are using. Try out [`WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch`](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/overview), current version (`JMeterWebSocketSamplers-0.12.jar`) doesn't seem to be having problems with parameterizing via [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

You can install the plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)